# how to open json file using python

Tags: python, json, google-colaboratory, jsonencoder

JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 8388729 (char 8388728)

```
import json
with open('tweets.json') as jfile:
  d = json.load(jfile)
```

> i tried using this code.but it did not work.
> this is the sample data
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3tNO.png)

Comment: Your json file is not valid json.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: try seeing the image i have provided i could not post the sample data.

Comment: @jkr pls check the image file

Comment: An image is not useful, especially one with only about 10K characters when the failing offset is 8.3M+.  Post text as *text*.  At a minimum, examine the text at the offset of the error, such as `jfile.read()[8388710:8388750]` and look at what is wrong.

Comment: You need to look into the "upstream" system that's generating 'tweets.json'.

Comment: Please [edit] to show the pertinent data in the input file; it seems your JSON data contains a formatting error. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error shows that your json data is not valid. There must be some syntax error in the json data. Specifically, it seems that there is a problem with the delimiter (':') at the specified line and column number.

You can use any JSON validator to find out the issue.
[You can try this](https://jsonlint.com/) or
[this with a pretty formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)